# Using jQuery, can I target an element to show its child element only when the parent element is being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I'm currently working on a page where ill have two elements, the parent and the child.

```
<div id="parent">Hi 
<span class="child">Bye</class> 
</div>
```

What I want is to have the child element displayed when the parent element is hovered over.  So I created a function in jQuery that will let me do exactly that.

```
function icondisplay(parentId){

 $(parentId).mouseenter(function() {

    $('.child').show();
});

$(hover).mouseleave(function() {

    $('.child').hide();

    });

}
```

The problem I'm having is that there are multiple parents within the page with different IDs, but the child elements are all the same class. So when I hover over any parent element, all of the child elements are displayed at once.  How can I make only the child element within the parent display, without going through and giving each child element a unique class/id then changing my function?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply need to change how you are selecting the parents and then selecting the childs:

```
$('.parentElement').hover(function()
{
    $(this).find('.child').show();
}, function()
{
    $(this).find('.child').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't use jQuery, use CSS.

```
.child {
    display: none;
}
*:hover > .child {
    display: inline;
}
```

I hesitate to add this, because the CSS approach makes so much more sense, but here we go:  If you must use jQuery, use `:has( > .child)`:

```
$("div:has(> .child)").hover(function()
    $("> .child", this).show();
}, function() {
    $("> .child", this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Yeah, much better solution than using jquery!

Comment: I think you need to worry about compatibility there, does IE support the CSS child selector?

Comment: @Andrew - If your users are using IE6, then you are right - you cannot use the child selector.  In that case you should give all the parents a common class and rely on the usual descendent selector.  But unless China is your target demographic, just don't support IE6.

Comment: @gilly3 I whole-heartedly agree. I just tend to tread on the side of caution when answering these questions because it's not always stated what's being supported, and I'd hate to give an answer that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with CSS.  Assume HTML something like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can do:

```
.child { display: none; }
.parent:hover > .child { display: inline; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would assume something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ex2nJ/1/ would solve your problem. for `$("div")` you can just put in your function to find whatever parent ID. However, you may not even need to.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  always makes it easier for me to understand an answer when there is a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$(parentId).mouseenter(function(){
    $(parentId > '.child').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

that would do

```
$(this).find('.child')
```

or

```
$('.child', this)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like that below

```
 $(parentId).mouseenter(function() {

    $(this).find('.child').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure can

```
$('#parent').hover(function(){
    $(this).children().show();
},function(){
    $(this).children().hide(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NkAnR/

And make sure to fix your closing <s>`span`</s>`</class>` tag